# Restcomm live call modification

Tags: restcomm

Trying to perform call transfer by using Live Call Modification. Client bob calls client alice and while call is in-progress I run following command line:

`curl -XPOST -u user:password http://192.168.0.100:8080/restcomm/2012-04-24/Accounts/ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf/Calls.json/CAa7c46f842cbf4dbdb1e0bc4715414577 -d "Url=http://192.168.0.100:8080/restcomm-rvd/services/apps/AP85e9ec/controller"`

However, command fails with
Futures timed out after [10 seconds]

By debugging Restcomm source (release 8.0.0.1114) I found source of the issue, it's

`cdr = dao.getCallDetailRecord(new Sid(callSid));
...
callPath = cdr.getCallPath(); // == NULL
Future future = (Future) ask(callManager, new GetCall(callPath), expires);`

Is it working as designed or it's a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you open an issue on github with logs and pacp and potentially investigate it and come up with a fix for it ?

Comment: sure, but what is pacp?

Comment: Sorry pcap is a Network trace that you can take with Wireshark or tcpdump